# Any idea how to get/query a list of storage accounts that have Queue/table/file/blob created in them using powershell/cli or any other way?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-storage-queues, azure-policy, azure-storage-account

Any idea how to get/query a list of  storage accounts that have Queue/table/file/blob created in them using powershell/cli or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to check if the Storage Account is being used is to check in Azure Monitor.

Navigate to Azure Monitor
Select Storage Accounts under Insights
Select Capacity to see if any of the services have utilization.

[Azure Monitor Storage Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GPSI.png)